# How to use foreach in Velocity template for Table

Tags: java, velocity, template-engine

I have an object invoice, it has some list of Invoice Items. Now I want to get print of my invoices. For that I used Velocity Template. But my model template not getting my required format.

**I used this** [image: First Used Format] .

**I got this Output**
[image: First Format Output]

**For below template**
[image: Second Format]

**I got this Output**
[image: Second Format Output]

**But I want like this**

[image: Required Format]

Guys Plz help me to get requried format

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Desp</th>
    <th>Qty></th>
    <td>Unit Price</th>
    <th>Disc</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>vat rate</th>
    <th>vat amount</th>
</tr>
#foreach ($titem in $!invoice.transactionItems)
    <tr>
        <td>$!titem.item.name</td>
        <td>$!titem.description</td>
        <td>$!titem.quantity</td>
        <td>$!titem.unitPrice</td>
        .....
    </tr>
#end
</table>
```

Firstly,you need to write some `html` code as well as `css`,once have the `html` template, you can fill your `object value` to the html code, as your format, you need to make use of the html `table` label to present your result.

Comment: It is fine for html. But I am preparing a pdf file to export. To prepare a pdf file I need docx template. In that temp I got this problem.